# Sparse least squares where the coeefficient matrix is not stored explicitly

Tags: least-squares, condition-number, sparse-matrices

Consider a bounded linear operator $A : U \to V$ where $U$ is finite dimensional and where $V$ is a separable Hilbert space, or with large dimension such that $A$ cannot be stored explicitly, being instead available as an algorithm for computing $y \mapsto Ay$. Let $f \in V$ and consider the standard least-squares problem: Find $x \in U$ such that $\|Ax-f\|=\text{min}!$. We assume that inner products of columns of $A$, i.e., the matrix elements of $M = A^*A$, can be computed efficiently, and similarly $A^*f$ can be computed efficiently. However, we also assume that that $M = A^*A$ is ill-conditioned.

Are there efficient algorithms for the solution of this least-squares problem that avoids the ill-conditioning of $A$?

Comment: Have you tried asking this question on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: What have you tried ? Do you know about GMRes ?

Comment: @G.Fougeron I currently solve the normal equations. $A^* A$ is very ill-conditioned, and something like QR would help tremendously. But since I don't have $A$ this seems not possible.

Comment: I will try scicomp!